# Null pointer exception when startin tomcat using axis 2 web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I trid to make a simple project to learn how to use web service with axis2.
So I trid to do like this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgY0pLadraE
But When I start my tomcat server, I had this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet.<clinit>(AxisAdminServlet.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then when I create my web service and run my project in the server, I get the first page where I have three links (services, validate and administration). When I click the services link I got this error :

```
type Rapport d''exception

message "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

cause mère

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Cause mère

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

cause mère

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

cause mère

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

cause mère

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix this? It's the first time for me to make a web service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, I think it's problem with tomcat configuration but I don't know how to fix it